# Executing a list of imported functions

Tags: python

I have a file with functions:

modules.py:

```
def a(str):
    return str + ' A'

def b(str):
    return str + ' B'
```

I want to perform these functions in cycle. Something like:

main.py:

```
import modules

modules_list = [modules.a, modules.b]
hello = 'Hello'

for m in modules_list:
    print m(hello)
```

The result should be:

```
>>> Hello A
>>> Hello B
```

This code is work. I do not want to use decorators, because too much functions in `modules.py`.
What is the best way? Thanks.

Comment: The code is good. He wants a more generalised approach, where the programmer doesn't have to specify the functions to be executed.

Comment: Don't use `str` as a variable name: def a(strg): return strg + ' A' def b(strg): return strg + ' B' Your program would work regardless of this, unless you're trying to use `str(foo)` somewhere else, but it's good practice to avoid shadowing built-in variable names.

Comment: @SukritKalra: I'm not sure - he says the program isn't working, not that he wants to optimize it.

Comment: I guess he wants a generalised approach, one that automatically gets the functions from the module and passes them the hello string sequentially.

Comment: @SukritKalra: That's a very...inspired guess.

Comment: The Code is working for me. I created module.py and main.py and run the same piece of code, only modification is instead of using parameter in both the subroutines as str I used strg. and no other difference.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. @Tim Pietzcker is right. It seems that I got typo in my real code. Indeed, the code is work. Edited.

Comment: what is `modules` here

Comment: @vlad: If the code works, do you still have a question?

Comment: @David Robinson, no. Everything is fine. Voted for alternative best looking variant :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
import modules
hello = 'Hello'
for m in dir(modules):
    obj = getattr(modules,m)
    if hasattr( obj, "__call__" ): #or use `if callable(obj):`
        print obj(hello)
```

**output:**

```
Hello A
Hello B
```

By the way, don't use `str` as a variable name, as `str` is already used as the name of a built-in function in Python.

Comment: Clarified the ending of your answer a bit

Answer (score 2):

```
import modules
hello = 'Hello'
for func in (x for x in modules.__dict__.values() if callable(x)):
    print func(hello)
```

You can also use the `inspect` module which sorts by name for you

```
import inspect
import modules
for name, func in inspect.getmembers(modules, callable):
    print func(hello)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be something you're looking for.

```
>>> for functions in dir(modules):
        if not functions.startswith("__"):
                eval("modules."+functions+"(\"Hello\")")

'Hello A'
'Hello B'
```

This is just a gross approximation. Certainly not a code I would put in a program.